# Seaborn tsplot not showing data

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to use seaborn to make a simple tsplot, but for reasons that aren't clear to me nothing shows up when I run the code. Here's a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(31), 'time': range(31)})

ax = sns.tsplot(data=df, value='value', time='time')
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

Usually tsplot you supply multiple data points for each time point, but does it just not work if you only supply one?

I know matplotlib can be used to do this pretty easily, but I wanted to use seaborn for some of its other functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing individual `unit`s. When using a data frame the idea is that multiple timeseries for the same `unit` have been recorded, which can be individually identifier in the data frame. The error is then calculated based on the different `unit`s.

So for one series only, you can get it working again like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(31), 'time': range(31)})
df['subject'] = 0
sns.tsplot(data=df, value='value', time='time', unit='subject')
```

Just to see how the error is computed, look at this example:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(31), 'time': range(31)})
    df['subject'] = i
    dfs.append(df)
all_dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
sns.tsplot(data=all_dfs, value='value', time='time', unit='subject')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `index` from column `time` and then plot `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(31), 'time': range(31)})
df = df.set_index('time')['value']
ax = sns.tsplot(data=df)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image: graph]